# How to imitate a class behaviour with implicit-cast operator

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

Suppose, there are 2 classes, Foo and ImitateFoo.
ImitateFoo implements an implicit cast operator to act like Foo.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int DoFoo() { return 1; }
};

class ImitateFoo
{
private:
    Foo f;

public:
    operator Foo&() { return f; }
};
```

I want to act on ImitateFoo, like I do on Foo. Especially calling its methods.

```
ImitateFoo imitator;

Foo& f = imitator; // implicit cast works
f.DoFoo();

static_cast<Foo&>(imitator).DoFoo(); // static cast works as well

imitator.DoFoo(); // does NOT compile -- desired behaviour!
```

Unfortunately, the last approach does not compile (at least with VS 10.0).
It's for some reasons not possible to overload the .-operator.

Any suggestions how I can achieve the desired behaviour? Is it somehow possible to increase the binding-priority of the cast-operator against the .-operator?

**Edit: Why I cannot use Inheritance as the most obvious solution**

I have to re-implement a bunch of framework classes. `Foo` resembles one of them and it's used as a *global object* throughout the legacy code (which I must not change).

Since I am now in need for unit tests, I need to control the state of these global objects. This is done quite similarly to the way the 
[PIMPL idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) proposes.

In that case the `ImitateFoo` class has only one state: it's implementation which is injected and might be changed during runtime. All method calls are redirected to this `Foo` instance. So actually I could implement the example above as easy as just make a `DoFoo` non-virtual function in `ImitateFoo` with redirects to its currents implementation method. Which is in fact what I am doing now.

This works pretty well both for methods and also for operators. But it results in A LOT of bloat code, which does nothing than redirecting.

Contrary to redirecting each method and operator-call by it's own, I wanted to take a step back and look if it's possible to just make the `ImitateFoo` behave like it's underlaying implementation.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that's possible.  But I like to be surprised about C++

Comment: short answer, no, it is not possible, but for this example specifically, you could simply have `ImitateFoo` inherit from `Foo`. Can you provide more details on why you need to do that?

Comment: There's a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4173.pdf) to allow that overload. But it won't be standard until at least 2017.

Comment: I'd advise you to do not rely on implicit behaviour. You may raise confusing results if you mix both classes.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I updated the question to explain why I cannot use inheritance.

Comment: You might want to look into std::reference_wrapper implementation, but you will still need to do casts to call Foo methods.

Comment: You'll be able to do such thing if this one comes into standard. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4173.pdf

Comment: @Windoze Thanks for linking this document. This is exactly what I was looking for. In 2.5 he is in fact stating, that this could be used for PImpl-like approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic languages like Python you could delegate all non explicitely defined methods to another object (here field `f`). But AFAIK it is not possible in C++.

If inheritance is not an acceptable solution you can *explicitely* delegate all methods you want `ImitateFoo` do process, in a kind of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) instead of inheritance :

```
class ImitateFoo
{
private:
    Foo f;

public:
    operator Foo&() { return f; }
    int DoFoo() { return f.DoFoo(); } // explicit delegation
};
```

It is not as automatic as you could want, but at least :

```
imitator.DoFoo();
```

will correctly compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit like a X Y problem, and your proposed solution, although elegant in concept, I don't believe it's possible in C++.

Running in a problem somewhat similar to yours I've used macros to hide the repetitive code, which in your case would be the casting(considering that the actual problem you want is to avoid is to re-write every function/operator , main goal being reducing the amount of code to be written) .

Here's a code snippet

```
#define CAST(x) (static_cast<Foo&>(x))
...
ImitateFoo f;
CAST(f).DoFoo();
```

Comment: My main limitation is to NOT change the legacy code anyhow, therefore this is unfortunately no solution. I assume duplicating each method and operator is the only possibility.